# XNA 2d Camera not drawing

Tags: c#, camera, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to implement a Camera class in XNA http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237979-2d-camera-in-xna/

It's not throwing up any errors when I try it, it simply doesn't draw anything inside it's targeted spritebatch. 
Tried making gigantic sprites or moving them around, to see if it was just placing them somewhere random. With no luck.

Declared it at the start of the game as:

```
Camera2D cam;
```

Then in my loadcontent():

```
cam = new Camera2D(Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
```

And lastly, in my Draw():

```
spriteBatch2.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, cam.Transform);

spriteBatch2.DrawString(arial, "Some text to say", new Vector2(300, 400), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Orange);

spriteBatch2.End();
```

Looked at Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport to double check it wasn't empty. It carried the locations 0,0,1920,1080. So I take it, origin point x,y and screen.width/height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uggh, noticed the update method in the class wasn't used anywhere in my game.

Putting

```
cam.Update();
```

Into my update method  got everything working correctly.